# Oghma Infinium, how is it in a locked Dwemer box, and why can't Herma-Mora just Recall It?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In skyrim, Oghama Infinium is trapped in a Dwemer lockbox. Herma-Mora has been manipulating Septimus Signus for many years to open the lockbox to free the book.

However, the book was last seen in the Oblivion Crisis, way past the time where all Dwemer has died. How was it locked in a Dwemer lockbox then?

Furthermore, the book is an artifact of Herma-Mora, and these artifacts can simply be recalled to the respective realm of Oblivion and given out again. He has certainly done it before.

- Mora promised the Oghma Infinium as a reward for defeating Graccus. However, the Prince [...] snatched it away upon Graccus' death

according to http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Oghma_Infinium

Why did Herma-Mora need to manipulate Septimus for many years to open the lockbox?

Comment: considering that the last known holder of the book was the Hero of Kvatch/Champion of Cyrodiil we could suspect it was his/her doing so it would not fall into the wrong hands. don't forget that Kagrenac's Tool's still worked long after he and most of the Dwemer disappeared, given that and a machine that can transcribe an Elder Scroll so that it's contents can be read without going blind one could assume that the Lockbox, being Dwemer made, was made to control the divine possibly by locking it away where not even Adra and Daedra can interfear

Comment: Does that suggest that if you kill septimus, Herma-Mora is somewhat screwed?

Comment: i wouldn't say screwed just delayed. there's always going to be someone Hermaeus Mora can use to do it's bidding in the mortal realm, the same with any of the Daedric Princes. though canon wise if the Dragonborn kills Septimus or obtains the book we don't know but we can assume that in the end the Princes get their wish. Clavicus Vile wants Umbra yet despite the option in Oblivion to give it to him in *The Infernal City* it's revealed that Umbra did end up in Clavicus Vile's Plane however it was able to escape

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the Hero of Kvatch/Champion of Cyrodiil could have done it. Septimus was manipulated most likely for a bit of entertainment by Hermaeus Mora, because he had/has the knowledge that the Dragonborn would open it, as he is the Daedric Prince of Forbidden Knowledge and (I think) Prophecy. The Dwemer were extremely advanced, and could have possibly made such a strong lockbox, defendant against magicka, and mortal weapons, *even* Daedric Artifices, that Hermaeus Mora couldn't have transported the Oghma Infinium away, and Kagrenac's Tools still work (As stated by Memor-X), leaving the possibility that it was locked in by the Hero of Kvatch much larger.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the dwemer used a technology so advanced that even the dark prince of knowledge could not brake the seal to get his precious book back. So he just tosses the job on a poor old man and doesn't even tell him the truth about what is in the box.